# Finding all solutions to trig questions

Tags: trigonometry

I know that trig equations can often have infinite solutions. For example: $\tan(\theta)=-1$ Here, $\theta=\frac{-\pi}{4},\frac{-3\pi}{4},\frac{-9\pi}{4}$ etc. I'm struggling with writing this out to express this, and having a similar problem with other trig equations. I tried $\frac{(n+1)pi}{4n}$ but that doesn't work. What can I do?

Comment: Are you claiming that $\cos\left(\frac\pi4\right)=-1$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos typo. Fixing right now

Comment: Are you claiming that $\tan\left(\frac\pi4\right)=-1$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos thank you IS this good?

Comment: It's better now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution to $\tan  \theta = \tan \alpha$ is given by $\theta = n\pi + \alpha$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ 
In your case, $\alpha = -\frac{\pi}{4}$ so the general solution can be written as $\theta = n\pi - \frac{\pi}{4},~ n \in \mathbb{Z} $

The proof for this is as follows:
$$\begin{align} \tan  \theta &\ = \tan \alpha \\
\dfrac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta} &\ = \dfrac{\sin\alpha}{\cos\alpha} \end{align} $$
$$ \sin\theta \cos\alpha - \sin\alpha \cos\theta = 0 ~;~ \cos\theta\cos\alpha \ne 0$$
$$ \sin(\theta-\alpha) = 0$$
$$ \theta - \alpha = n\pi ~; ~n \in \mathbb{Z}$$
$$ \theta  = n\pi + \alpha ~; ~n \in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: Are there general solutions for the other trig equations

Comment: Also, is it $\theta=n\pi\pm\alpha$? I was looking into this and found somewhere where it had the plus minus and was wondering if they made a mistake.

Comment: @Burt No, it is definitely $\theta = n\pi + \alpha$. You can very easily check why $n\pi \pm \alpha$ is wrong. $\tan(\pi - \alpha) = -\tan\alpha \ne \tan\alpha$. And for your other question, yes, there are general solutions for other trigonometric functions too. For example, general solution for $\sin\theta = \sin\alpha$ is $\theta = n\pi + (-1)^n \alpha$ and general solution for $\cos\theta = \cos\alpha$ is $\theta = 2n\pi \pm \alpha$

Answer (score 3):

Your principal root of $\tan\theta=-1$ is $\theta=-\frac\pi 4$. From there, because $\tan \theta$ is $\pi$-periodic, adding or subtracting $k\pi, (k\in \Bbb Z)$ yields another solution.

So, our solutions are given by $\theta=-\frac\pi 4+k\pi=\frac{4k-1}{4}\pi, k\in\Bbb Z$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count by $a$'s starting at $b$, then you'd write

$$an+b$$

where $n$ is a non-negative integer.

Your solutions should be

$$\frac{3\pi}{4}, \frac{7\pi}{4}, \frac{11\pi}{4}, \ldots.$$

So you want numerator to count by $4$'s starting at $3$.  The numerator is

$$(4n+3)\pi$$

and the denominator is always $4$.

Let $n$ be negative to get all the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, $\tan\left(-\frac\pi4\right)=-1$. Since the restriction of $\tan$ to $\left(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right)$ is injective, there is no other point of that interval with that property. And now it follows from the fact that $\tan$ is periodic with period $\pi$ that$$\tan(\theta)=-1\iff\theta=n\pi-\frac\pi4$$for some $n\in\Bbb Z$.