# General Equations for Cot, Sec, and csc

Tags: trigonometry

After asking [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4221498/finding-all-solutions-to-trig-questions/4221514#4221514) I came to the understanding that the trig equations have general solutions. I was able to find that the general solution of $\tan(\theta)=\tan(\alpha)$ is $\theta=n\pi+\alpha$ (thanks to all those who helped) and that $\sin(\theta)=\sin(\alpha)$ is $\theta=n\pi+(-1)^n\alpha$ and that $\cos(\theta)=\cos(\alpha)$ is $\theta=2n\pi\pm\alpha$

Is the answer to this that it is the same as their reciprocal trig equations? If $\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}=\sec(\theta)$, then we are looking for $\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}=\frac{1}{\cos(\alpha)}$ which seems to be the same as the cosine.

Comment: Except you need to avoid the points of non-definition (when $\cos(x)=0$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so it would be the same, but $\theta\neq\frac{\pi}{2}$ for sec, for example.

Comment: More than just that value. But, yes $\sec(\theta)=\sec(\alpha)$ if and only if $\cos(\theta)=\cos(\alpha)$ **and** $\cos(\theta)\neq 0$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin so $\theta\neq2n\pi\pm\frac{\pi}{2}$